# Wagtail API- Vue.js get request authorization?

Tags: vue.js, cors, wagtail, vue-resource, django-cors-headers

Goal: Connect vue.js to Wagtail-API/pages.

I have configured the wagtail API v2 as per the [setup guide](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/advanced_topics/api/v2/configuration.html), however, the Vue-resource get request is not working out.

Console Error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/: Response to preflight
request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource.
```

Searching the error leads me to believe that I should implement CORS. However, I have seen a few Django_rest + Vue.js tutorials and none have mentioned CORS. Is it truly necessary to implement CORS? Also, should I use Axios rather than vue-resource?

Relevant vue.js and wagtail-API code below:

---

The following HTML is based on [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-rest-vuejs/) tutorial. The current pages print, but the ones I am requesting do not.

HTML/Django_template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.0"></script>

<div id="test">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="print_test in pages">
            <p> [[print_test]]</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var app=new Vue({
    el: "#test",
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data: function(){
            return {
            search: '',
            pages: [
              { id: '1', title: 'one'},
              { id: '2', title: 'two'},
              { id: '3', title: 'three'}
            ]};
    },

    http: {
        root: 'http://localhost:8000',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'CAUSING ERROR...'
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getPages: function () {
            this.$http.get('api/v2/pages/?type=blog.blogpage').then(function (data,status,request) 
            {
            if (status == 200) {
                this.pages = data;
                console.log(data);
             }   
            })
        }
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.getPages();
    }

    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

---

The following covers my API setup– provided in case I missed something.

settings/base.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'wagtail.api.v2',
]
```

api.py:

```
from wagtail.api.v2.endpoints import PagesAPIEndpoint
from wagtail.api.v2.router import WagtailAPIRouter
from wagtail.wagtailimages.api.v2.endpoints import ImagesAPIEndpoint
from wagtail.wagtaildocs.api.v2.endpoints import DocumentsAPIEndpoint

api_router = WagtailAPIRouter('wagtailapi')

api_router.register_endpoint('pages', PagesAPIEndpoint)
api_router.register_endpoint('images', ImagesAPIEndpoint)
api_router.register_endpoint('documents', DocumentsAPIEndpoint)
```

urls.py:

```
from .api import api_router
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    url(r'^api/v2/', api_router.urls),
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
]
```

blog/model.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.http import HttpResponse
from wagtail.api import APIField

class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory', blank=True)
```

Comment: Required reading ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. FYI, it's got nothing to do with the frameworks / technology chosen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: So, I believe the API is called through the root of the site's domain. Is localhost not pointing to the appropriate domain? replacing it with 127.0.0.1 stops the error, though vue and the api are still not passing data...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why there was an issue with localhost. However, I finally got lucky and the following worked!

```
methods: {getPages: function () {
               this.$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/pages/').then(
                   response => {this.pages = response.data})}
        },
```

Interesting note: data is still passed when localhost is used, however, the error still pops up.